# Когда нужно разделять поля?

Tags: база-данных

Когда необходимо разделять поля, например, адрес, чтобы соблюдалась 1 нормальная форма. И можно ли не разбивать адрес на город, улицу и тд., если я не собираюсь выполнять запросы по этим полям?

Comment: Зависит от задачи, очевидно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случие где ети поля обезательние для заполнения, лушче соблюдать первую нормальную форму, поскольку даже если функционал не подразумевает использование выборки по этим полям, он может меняться. В случае с адресом лучше разбивать, если под ним понимается набор перечисленных сущностей (город, улица), если адрес это единая сущность, к примеру той которой используєтся в качестве контактной информации владельца сайта, целесообразно для простоты и удобности заполнения хранить в одном поле.